# Query Feature Class Can we edit in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop

Is there any option to edit the Query  feature class in ArcGIS Desktop as I am working on Time Zone project where the Query feature class is polygon and I need to edit , but its not editable ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. By "Query feature class", do you mean "Query Layer"? Query Layers are mostly read-only, but you can execute an `arcpy.ArcSDESSQLExecute` cursor to edit them via SQL.